# Is the Reputation tab summary incorrect?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

I wanted to report a small UI bug.

It happens on my desktop and on my iOS app too.

In my reputation tab I see Reverse Engineering with 1 of reputation:

[image]

If I click on that site profile I am listed at 101 of reputation:

[image]

I attach to the +100 that seem missing from the summary tab:

[image]

I waited some days (+-7) to report, just in case it's temporary, but it seems to stay.

Comment: Earlier today I got kicked off in the iosapp, and I had to relog, and now it seem to work, so I would say thanks it now work (on ios and desktop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These numbers take a while to sync up.

They have now.

Comment: The only reason I reported is that +100 was in my ´last 30 days' :) must had been a small glitch, as usually its fast