# Mismatching rep number in top-left dropdown list on mobile?

Tags: bug, reputation, mobile-web

As you can see, in the first picture below, there's an obvious discrepancy, no matter how I refresh the page or what site I'm on. However it's corrected after five minutes or so.

[image: before]
[image: after]

Comment: Related; https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301924/337838

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Whee, caching is fun!](/a/221414/335772)

Your rep is stored on each site plus on some global database. That global one is updated less often to save server load.